# Am I not using Concerns Properly in Rails 4.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I was playing around with concerns and I cam across an interesting issues I did the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RoleData
end

class User
  module RoleData
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods

      def role
        roles.first.try(:role)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

But now when I do `rails c` and do `user = User.find(5)` and then do `user.role` it tells me that this object has no role method: `NoMethodError: undefined method`role' for #`

So, what am I doing wrong? I was watching [ryan bates about concerns and services](http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects?view=asciicast) and I am confused. Why is there no role method for this user class?

I run my tests and they fail, not because of a load issue, but because of missing or undefined methods that are clearly defined, like I can't even do `current_user.role`.

I am sure it is something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because you defined `role` method as class method, you even don't need `Concern` for defining simple instance method, so you could write:

```
module RoleData
  def role
    roles.first.try(:role)
  end
end
```

if you need something more then just instance method you could write:

```
module RoleData
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # block will be executed in User class after including RoleDate
    # you could write here `has_many`, `before_create` etc.
    # ....
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # class methods
    # ....
  end

  # instance methods
  # ....
end
```